# How to mock database results in service layer unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jdbc, junit, mockito

I'm new to Mocking things in Unit tests and I've started experimenting with Mockito. Is the following possible using Mockito?

I am trying to write unit tests for a layered webservice application. At this point I am testing the Service layer, which calls the DAO layer to acquire data from the database.
I need to mock the database results so that I'm not making real update calls to the database every time my unit tests run.

I was thinking of doing this by mocking the DAO object that my service layer calls, but I need to do that without changing the source code. If I'm currently unit testing the service layer, how can I make it use a mocked DAO layer?

My Unit Test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testUpdate() {
RequestObject request = new RequestObject();
request.setEntityId(1234);
request.setLob('testLOB');
ResponseObject response = service.updateMember(request);
}
```

My Service method:

```
public ResponseObject updateMember(RequestObject request) {
ResponseObject result = DAO.updateMember(request);
}
```

Is it possible to Mock the DAO without mocking the Service in this instance? 
EDIT: I am using Maven for dependency management.

Comment: What dependency management system do you use? (Maven/Gradle)
And can you add your dependencies to your question, this has an effect on the possible answers that can be given.

Comment: How hard mocking the DAO within the service-to-test is, depends on how you can inject a mocked DAO into the service. Does e.g. the service's constructor allow passing in a DAO instance, or a factory that could create mocked DAOs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Mocker like Mokito in the setup of your test. Something like:

```java
public class YouTestClass {

    @MockBean
    DAO mockedDAO;
...
@Test
public void testUpdate() {
        Mockito.when(mockedDAO.updateMember(Mockito.isA(RequestObject.class)).thenReturn(new ResponseObject());
RequestObject request = new RequestObject();
request.setEntityId(1234);
request.setLob('testLOB');
ResponseObject response = service.updateMember(request);
}
```

You will need to adjust the `.thenReturn(new ResponseObject());` to ResponseObject you actually want to receive for the test. Also you DAO class seems to be a static class, so you might need to read on how to mock that if at all possible. Otherwise you might want to make it a singleton.

Comment: The line that confuses me here is the Mockito.when method. Doesn't this just tell Mockit to always return the specified value when the service method is called? I would want to specify what the DAO returns, not the service.

Answer (score 1):

if you are testing on the service layer for example, you could do something like this.

```
@Mock
private DAO dao;

@Test
public void testUpdate() {

   RequestObject request = new RequestObject();
   request.setEntityId(1234);
   request.setLob('testLOB');

   ResponseObject result = //the response that you want

   when(dao.updateMember(eq(request))).thenReturn(result);

   ResponseObject response = service.updateMember(request);

   // ASSERTIONS HERE
}
```

Comment: As the TO is new to `Mockito` you might want to add an example how to inject the `DAO` into the `service`. Also please try to indent your example code to improve the readability.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was basically: when I invoke the DAO through the Service call as for instance
'''when(AccountManagerImpl.saveAccount(testAccount)).thenReturn(mockedAccount)'''. 
The challenge is when the method returns void i.e. just dumps some data into a table. This means you have to confirm the method invocation indirectly. In my case I use 'verify(mockedAccount, times(1)).saveAccount)'. 
This only gives assurance that the method was invoked at least once. There are of course deeper layers. If you want to confirm that the data was written to an actual table then naturally you'll need a more robust test harness i.e. set up a test database etc. Or you can do the cheaper [and arguably less constrained] alternative of simply mocking the result set by for instance 
    when(mockPreparedStmnt.execute()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE) 
This of course makes a tonne of assumptions which could come back and bite you. You are basically saying - lets assume that the data got saved correctly. But what if that assumption ITSELF is the SUT? I just bring it up during Code Review - here's where a test coverage Matrix will save you many nights.